# Copy content from div to textarea in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

***Main Target :***

To create a website that will have a live preview of an HTML/CSS code. [LINK](http://apolosiskos.co.uk/stack.html)

***More specifically :***

The HTML/CSS code will be editable form the user in some specific parts. So, the code in the live preview will not derive from text areas but from divs.

***Image of what I am trying to do :***
[image]

***Progress so far :***
So, in my previous questions :

a) [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157410/live-html-css-preview-from-a-div-tag-and-not-a-text-area-tag/40157883?noredirect=1#comment67991386_40157883)

b) [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40362188/replace-parts-of-string-attributes-in-textarea-using-input-boxes/40366991#40366991)

I tried to find a way to make the live preview box work after getting the code from the black boxes. It did not work because the code was given in a `div` tag and not a `textarea`. I would like to add that the code in the `div` tags use `xmp` tags because some parts are editable from the user.

So, I found out that the best solution is to keep the `div` tags in order for the user to change/alter the code and then use a hidden `textarea` that will be used for the live preview.

***Main Question :***

How can I copy the content of the div in the `textarea`? I am using a JS script (below) to copy it in the clipboard. Is it possible to copy it in the `textarea` content?

After I do this, I will try to make it work without a copy(update code) button. 
Here is my script :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

  var highestBox = 0;
  $('.top').each(function() {
    if ($(this).height() > highestBox) {
      highestBox = $(this).height();
    }
  });
  $('.top').height(highestBox);

});

document.getElementById("copyButton1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    copyToClipboard(document.getElementById("copyTarget1"));
});

document.getElementById("copyButton2").addEventListener("click", function() {
    copyToClipboard(document.getElementById("copyTarget2"));
});

function copyToClipboard(elem) {
      // create hidden text element, if it doesn't already exist
    var targetId = "_hiddenCopyText_";
    var isInput = elem.tagName === "INPUT" || elem.tagName === "textarea";
    var origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd;
    if (isInput) {
        // can just use the original source element for the selection and copy
        target = elem;
        origSelectionStart = elem.selectionStart;
        origSelectionEnd = elem.selectionEnd;
    } else {
        // must use a temporary form element for the selection and copy
        target = document.getElementById(targetId);
        if (!target) {
            var target = document.createElement("textarea");
            target.style.position = "absolute";
            target.style.left = "-9999px";
            target.style.top = "0";
            target.id = targetId;
            document.body.appendChild(target);
        }
        target.textContent = elem.textContent;
    }
    // select the content
    var currentFocus = document.activeElement;
    target.focus();
    target.setSelectionRange(0, target.value.length);

    // copy the selection
    var succeed;
    try {
          succeed = document.execCommand("copy");
    } catch(e) {
        succeed = false;
    }
    // restore original focus
    if (currentFocus && typeof currentFocus.focus === "function") {
        currentFocus.focus();
    }

    if (isInput) {
        // restore prior selection
        elem.setSelectionRange(origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd);
    } else {
        // clear temporary content
        target.textContent = "";
    }
    return succeed;
}
```

Cheers

Comment: this could help with setting the value in the textarea: [innerhtml](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, you can simply use the `val()` method, e.g.:
`$('#myTextarea').val('content that goes into the textarea');`

Comment: That worked. I want to make it delete the previous content now and it is set :)

Comment: @reinder Can you give me your opinion on my answer? I posted one below. It works but I want to know if it sounds good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combined many things I found online and made it work using this script:

```
    var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('copyTarget2');
    var MyDiv2 = document.getElementById('copyTarget1');

    $('#Update').click(function(e) {

      textareahtml.value=$.trim(MyDiv1.innerText) 
      textareacss.value=$.trim(MyDiv2.innerText)
   });
```

and I put a button in my HTML code.